# Will Thread be garbage collected in this example after thread.join()?

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection

Will RAM resources be released by `w1_th` and `w2_th` after `w1_th.join()` and `w1_th.join()` is executed? I have a much more complicated script with a similar structure and RAM usage seems to be increasing with every while loop. To put in a different way, I want to ensure RAM resources are freed once a loop is over.

```py
from multiprocessing import Event, Lock
from threading import Thread

def worker(**kwargs):
     # do some work and save output to some (eg .csv) file


def topmethod(**kwargs):
    signal_to_stop.set = kwargs['signal_to_stop']
    while not signal_to_stop.set():
        # worker 1 
        w1_th = Thread(target=worker, daemon=False, kwargs={'foo':1})
        w1_th.start()
        w2_th = Thread(target=worker, daemon=False, kwargs={'foo':2})
        w2_th.start()
        w1_th.join()
        w2_th.join()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal_to_stop = Event()
    top_th = Thread(target=topmethod, daemon=False, kwargs={'signal_to_stop':signal_to_stop})
    top_th.start()
    try:
        top_th.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        signal_to_stop.set()
        print("Ending program")
```

Comment: Check out `gc.collect()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html

Comment: I have read other answers mentioning garbage collection but advise against using it manually. But then does performing `gc.collect()` ensure the RAM used by the terminated thread would be released? Pardon me but I am new to figuring out resource management in Python.

Comment: As a rule, Python will keep allocating more memory as long as there is memory available. It will collect when it tries to allocate more memory but no memory is available. Python is fairly efficient about maintaining memory. The only time you would manually collect is to prevent gc from running during an important process. To ensure your objects are released, set all references to None when done with them.

Comment: So should I do something like `del w1_th` after `w1_th.join()` is completed and then issue `gc.collect()`?

Comment: Yes - That should help with the collection